# How to use Doors to load levels in godot 3d

Tags: 3d, godot

just started playing around with Godot and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle level switching in my game.

The game world is split into 3 distinct levels:

1. Outside
2. Inside Level 1
3. Inside Level 2

Outside and Inside Level 1 are connected, and Inside Level 1 and Level 2 are connected

I need a way to make it so that when a player interacts with a door object the game loads the level necessary AND spawns the player at the correct spawn point.
So when the player goes from Inside Level 1 to Outside, they need to spawn right infront of the door object in the Outside Level instead of Outside's default spawn location. The same is true of when the Player goes from Inside Level 2 back to Inside Level 1.

I just learned about singletons/autoload so I figure I need to set up some kind of level manager but Im not exactly sure how. I also don't know how to set the player's transform to be the same as the spawn point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an autoload.

*We can really over-engineer this. There are many variations, as you will see below. But there are a set of steps you are going to follow. In the interest of not bloating this answer, I'll cover them in broad terms.*

This is what you are going to do:

- In the scenes add a `Position3D` for each door. This `Position3D` will be where you will place the player character when it enters from the corresponding door. And give the `Position3D` a name that you can figure out form the name of the door.
- Store in a variable in the autoload which door the player interacted with. This is what we are going to use to find the `Position3D` on the new scene. *The code in the door will either call a method on the autoload, or set the variable directly.*
- Change scenes, by whatever means you prefer (it can be from the code in the door, or a method in the autoload - it can be with the scene tree methods or manually - you can load, preload or load interactively the new scene). *Interactive load avoid freezing the game during the load. Which allows you have an animation to hide the load time.*
- After the new scene is loaded, instantiated and in the scene tree… Get the corresponding `Position3D` with the value stored in the autoload (if there is any).
- Now you are going to place the player character at the `Position3D` you found. This might mean to move it, if you have the player character as part of the scene. Or a method in the autoload spawns the character in the correct position. *Or you might even remove the player character from the old scene, store it in the autoload, and after the new scene is ready, add it to it. In fact, it is possible to make the player character itself an autoload.* Regardless of how you get the reference to the character player, you are going to make sure its `global_transform` is set to the `global_transform` of the `Position3D` you found (if there was any). *If there wasn't, then put (or let) the player character at a default position.*

**Addendum**: If you only want the position instead of the transform, you can use `global_transform.origin`. *There isn't a `global_position` in 3D in Godot 3, however it was added in Godot 4.*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!
So here's what I've got so far:

1. Global singleton script used for storing variables relating to the player (health, spawnpoint, etc)
2. Events singleton script used for storing all signals in the game which can be emitted elsewhere
3. Main scene that loads the player as a child, as well as a spatial node which loads the level as a child of itself

However, when I try to pass the spawn point information to the player, Godot gives me "Error setting propery 'global_transform' with value of type Nil

Comment: At the beginning of the game and whenever the player interacts with the door, a signal is emitted to the current_level spatial node in the main scene to grab a reference of the position3D node called "Start" and to set the Global.playerspawn variable to be the global_transform of the position 3D.

Comment: ` func playerSetup(): #Called once at the beginning of the game, and everytime a new level is loaded
 global_transform = Global.playerSpawn
 health = Global.currentHP
 currentAmmo = Global.currentClip
 totalAmmo = Global.currentAmmo `

Comment: @zwan9 "of type Nil" is telling you that the variable which you are trying to access has been literally set to `null`, perhaps where you set that variable you can also pull the `Transform` you need. Know that autoloads are loaded in order. Also, perhaps using `is_instance_valid` is the right call to check (instead of `== null`), since it will also checks if you have a reference to a freed object.