# How make 3d player spawn back to its original position after coming out of a house in Godot

Tags: 3d, godot

Hey they guys I am making a 3d game in which I have some houses but when my player enters the house after coming out of the house it spawns back to the position from which it started and I want that it spawn infront of the gate. If you have any solution then please tell me.

I have tried following some 2d tutorials on YouTube but they aren't working for my case.
In one tutorial his code contains global_position which is not a variable but when I am writing global_position in my code it says it isn't declared....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Doors to load levels in godot 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213738/how-to-use-doors-to-load-levels-in-godot-3d)

Comment: Can you edit your post (don't put the code in a comment) to contain the code for how you switch the level? A possible solution would be to not delete the player, but to "transfer" it to the newly loaded scene at the correct position.

Comment: @Camwin Okay I will try it

Comment: @Theraot yes your solution is working can you please post it as a answer so other people can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey they guy's finally I have solved this error.
The solution is, follow this tutorial - https://youtu.be/9fbnuKkj5Fw
and in the global script for 3d game, use -

var player_pos : Vector3

Instead of Vector2

And in the place of global_position use global_transform.origin and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to not delete the player when switching levels, and instead move them to the proper position in the newly loaded scene based on what door the player entered.

An exit door could store coordinates, a transform, an object name, or other information to assist with moving the player.

Just make sure the player isn't part of any level scenes anymore to prevent duplicate players.